# Алгоритм увеличения пароля

Tags: java, android, алгоритм, криптография, соль

Пользователь вводит пароль: например "123" - нужно увеличить размер пароля до 16 символов. При этом чтобы каждый раз вводя исходный пароль - увеличенный генерировался одинаковый. Тоесть рандом не подоходит.

Answer (score 2):

1. Пользователь вводит pass = 123
2. Генерируем мд5 на основе изначального пароля
3. Отсекаем от мд5 генерации определённое кол-во символов,
   чтобы 123+кусок_отсечённого_мд5_кода = 16 символов
4. ...
5. Профит :)

Comment: а есть ли конкретный пример готового решения?

Comment: hashCode() - оказался не совсем подходящим. Вот пример генерации md5 https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/java__java-md5-hashing-example
1. получил пароль 2. на его основе получил мд5 3. посчитал сколько изначальный пароль составляет символов 4. вырезал из мд5 необходимое кол-во (до итоговых 16 символов) 5. приклеил к паролю

Answer (score 1):

В криптографии такое "увеличение" длины пароля называется [соль (salt)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))

По сути это более-менее случайная строка (возможно с участием самого пароля)

По сути его можно хранить в преференсах приложения ибо это не бог весь какой секрет, обладание атакующим солью пароля практически не добавляет бенефитов, поскольку весь смысл соли в противодействии [радужным таблицам](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)

С другой стороны ТС говорит об увеличении длины пароля, которая не хранится/нельзя хранить  открыто - такая штука называется [перец (pepper)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)). В вычислении перца из пароля не вижу особого смысла, поскольку - хэш пароля который принято хранить в БД и так вычисляется из пароля, так что в вычислении перца из пароля нет ни логики, ни дополнительной безопасности.

Исходя из этого, вижу 2 варианта перчения:

1. Вычисление перца как хэш из логина (или другой информации о юзере)
2. Рандоманя генерация перца и его хранение в шифрованном виде (в качестве ключа можно использовать, например [уникальный идентификатор устройства](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) )

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант

```
DigestUtils.md5Hex("123").substring(0, 16)
```